# Angular 8 application with ADFS 2.0 authentication

Tags: angular, adfs

I have an Angular 8 application and I need to implement authentication using ADFS 2.0. Could anyone please provide me pointers or a sample application?

Comment: You got a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use ADFS, you need an Angular client that supports one of:

- WS-Fed
- SAML 2.0
- OpenId Connect / OAuth

Typically, you would use the latter but the protocol is not supported by ADFS 2.0.